# How many ways to completely reorder n elements

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a formula for the number of ways to completely reorder n elements?

Here by "completely reorder" I'm implying that no element is where it was initially.

e.g. for 3 elements - 123:

231, 312

Comment: look at number of dearrangements

Comment: @28ADY0901 thanks!